# Which UART is used in STM32G0 bootloader

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I have a board with a micro STM32G031 contains two USARTs. I want to download firmware through the bootloader. Which UART is used for it? Only UART1 or both?

Comment: what part of the st documentation did you not understand?

Comment: If you've found out about the bootloader UART programming procedure, did you find the application note about how it works with flow diagrams?